# Showing another Form from menu item click

Tags: delphi

I am very new in delphi and working on old delphi project. I want to call another form when I click on the menu item. I have this procedure below. Now I don't have `NotifyClose` and `RunFormOption` values inside current form unit to pass as parameter to `ShowScreens(...)` procedure of another unit. How should I do? Any suggestion, please?

```
procedure TForm.ShowScreens(Owner: TForm;
 Device: TComponent; RunFormOption:Integer; NotifyClose: TNotifyEvent);

begin
  FUsed:=True;
  onSetupClose:=onSetupClose;
  MakeConnection(device,NotifyClose);
end;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please, read your question from our view and you will see that we can't understand anything. Reformat the question if you want help.

Comment: FWIW, for RunFormOption I'd go for either 42 or 666.

Comment: @David, but that might open evil import text file dialog box ([`xlDialogImportTextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194519(v=office.15).aspx)).

Comment: I get a feeling that OP isn't actually asking how to show second form but how to get those two missing parameters which are probably declared or set in some other unit. If that is the real question then the answer is add that unit into uses section. It might be necessary to create new uses section in implementation section to avoid cyclical referencing if that other units has this unit added in uses section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show a Form after clicking a MenuItem , right?
Just add something like

```
procedure YourMainFormName.onClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    YourNewFormName.Show;
end;
```

to the TMenuItem's OnClick Procedure (assign one through the Obspect Inspector - F11)

just make sure you include "YourNewFormName" in the uses part of "YourMainFormName"

I hope this solved your question. Good luck.

Comment: Better have action assigned to a menu item. (I'm starting to feel like an [actions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/What_Is_an_Action) propagator :-)

Comment: @TLama I have seen actions in Delhi code before and aware of how the construction works, but what are the advantages? I only see it as unnecessary extra coding, but once again I could be wrong.

Comment: @mg30rg, there's no extra coding behind. The code that you execute is written once. Assigned can be to many UI controls (since you can assign the same action e.g. to a button and to a menu item). Also, they are managed from one place (action list) which is easier than hunting event handlers of many controls.

Comment: @TLama Ok, but what are the advantages against i.e. a standard (class) method called from the event handler. (Which would normally be used to prevent redundant coding.) Please understand that I don't wish to argue here, I'm just curious.

Comment: @mg30rg, sure that you are not supposed to write the code that is going to be executed in the action's `OnExecute` event handler, but call a function or method of a certain class from there. I'm promoting actions because I worked with a few systems that were using event handlers instead of actions and it's been painful to find their event methods. If they were using actions, I would just open action list and find an action with some sensible name.

Comment: @TLama So basically you are promoting actions as a substitute of the basic principle of separating business logic from user interface (and separating foreground logic from background logic)?

Comment: @mg30rg, yup, instead of events handlers.

Comment: @TLama I understand now. I don't really like the idea because I don't really like when programmatic functions are spread all over the designer (yes, I hate when they define SQL commands/connection strings/initial values etc. in the designer too) and could not be found with reading **only** the source code files (and as far as i know an action is paired to an event in the designer instead of the code) but that is the matter of taste.